# Смена архитектуры на сервере

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Есть удалённый виртуальный сервер. Когда я его арендовал, то поставил туда Ubuntu Server x32. Сейчас потребовалось сменить систему на 64-битную.

Вопрос: Как правильно переустановить ОС, вместе со всеми ныне установленными пакетами, и не потерять хранящиеся на сервере данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делай бэкап конфигурационных файлов сервера и всего установленного вами программного обеспечения. Устанавливайте операционную систему c поддержкой 64-й архитектуры. Устанавливайте все ваши пакеты.Восстанавливайте ваши конфигурационные файлы.

Comment: Это-то понятно, но как бы получить список всех установленных пакетов и перенести их на новую систему (я ж их наизусть не помню)?

Comment: список всех установленных пакетов dpkg -l подробнее тут http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages